# Send Input Data on Ajax Call and process in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I want to send input field data on change via Ajax Call to PHP File and then check this data into Database if available then display error message and if not then display success message.

Below is my code - 
Html Code -

```html
<lable class="required">Guillemot Reference Number:<em>*</em></lable><span><input type="text" name="case_number" id="case_number" class="input-text required-entry" value="" onChange="checkReferenceNumber()"/> <p class="case_number_warning" style="color:red; vertical-align: bottom; font-size: smaller; display:inline;"> Already Exists </p></span>
```

Javascript -

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
     $('.case_number_warning').hide();
     $("#case_number").on('change', function(){
      $('.case_number_warning').hide();
      var datetime = d.getTime();
      var case_number = $('#case_number').val();
      $.ajax({
          url: '/checkReferenceNumber.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data:({
       action  : 'checkrefno',
       case_number : case_number
        }),
    
          success:function(result) {
       alert("Sent"); 
       var response = JSON.stringify(result);
       },
          error: function() { alert("Already Exists"); $('.case_number_warning').show(); }
      });      
     });
    });
    
    </script>
    <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Php File checkReferenceNumber.php code -

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require_once '/var/www/html/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
Mage::app('default');
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

    $action = trim($_REQUEST['action']);
    $case_number = trim($_POST['case_number']);
    /*
    $action = 'checkrefno';
    $case_number = 'Ref-12345678';
    */

    if($action == 'checkrefno'){
        $refno_output = $connection->fetchOne("select reference_number from guillemot_reference_number where reference_number = '".$case_number."'");
        if($refno_output) {
            echo    "\nReferece no - ". $refno_output;
        }
    }
?>
```

In this I want to check input filed data is available in database or not on Ajax Onchange event if data is available it should return message that data is available or true or false.

I want to get response data from php code.  How to return data to phtml file from php code. and display error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP use `exit` if reference number is found like,

```
........
    if($action == 'checkrefno'){
        $refno_output = $connection->fetchOne("select reference_number from guillemot_reference_number where reference_number = '".$case_number."'");
        if($refno_output) {
            echo $refno_output;
            exit;
        }
    }
    echo 'NOTFOUND'; // status NOT FOUND ref code
    exit;
?>
```

In Jquery use

```
$("#case_number").on('change', function(){
    $('.case_number_warning').hide();
    var datetime = d.getTime();
    var case_number = this.value; // use simple this.value here
    $.ajax({
        url: '/checkReferenceNumber.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:({
            action  : 'checkrefno',
            case_number : case_number
        }),
        success:function(result) {
            alert("Sent");  
            if(result==="NOTFOUND"){
                alert("Not Exists");
            }  else {
                alert("Ref Num "+result+" already Exists");
                $('.case_number_warning').show(); 
            }               
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `die(json_encode());` function on PHP file

```
if($refno_output) {
            die(json_encode($refno_output));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see you are using JSON to get data from PHP in JS

```
            success:function(result) {
            alert("Sent");  
            var response = JSON.stringify(result);
            },
```

So, you can return JSON string in PHP

```
if($action == 'checkrefno'){
    $refno_output = $connection->fetchOne("select reference_number from guillemot_reference_number where reference_number = '".$case_number."'");
    if($refno_output) {
        $return = array("success" => true, "refno" => $refno_output);
        echo json_encode($return);
    }else{
        $return = array("success" => false, "error" => "Some error");
        echo json_encode($return);
    }
}
```

and use it in JS

```
            success:function(result) {
            alert("Sent");  
            var err = false;
            var response = null;
            try{
                response = JSON.parse(result);
            }catch(e){
                err = true;
                console.error(e);
            }
            if(response.success && !err){
                //do something with response.refno
            }else{
                //if error
            }
            },
```